# Control Instances of a class

Tags: c#, constructor

I have implemented a class as below:

```
public class Person
{
    public int d, e, f;
    public Person()
    {
    }

    public Person(int a)
    {
    }

    public Person(int a, int b)
    {
        new Person(40, 6, 8);
    }

    public Person(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        d = a; e = b; f = c;
    }
}   

public  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person P = new Person(100, 200);

        Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", P.d, P.e, P.f);// it prints 0,0,0
    }
}
```

Now if I create the instance of Person class with two arguments I am unable to set the values of d,e,f which is because in the third constructor a new object of Person is declared all together.

So the previous object does not have any idea about this new one.

Is there any way I can get hold of this new object and assign values to d,e,f from there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377888/how-can-i-use-multiple-constructors-to-remove-duplicated-code-while-maintaining

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're *actually* trying to chain constructors together, so that one constructor passes arguments to another:

```
public Person(int a, int b) : this(40, 6, 8)
{
}
```

It's odd that you're ignoring `a` and `b` though... normally you'd just default one value, e.g.

```
public Person(int a, int b) : this(a, b, 8)
{
}
```

See [my article on constructor chaining](http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/constructors.html) for more details.

Comment: Hi Jon, this is not an inheritance scenario. I i try to do this I get compile time error as "Person.Person cannot call itself". All I want to do is in main when I try to print the values of d,e,f I want it should be printed as 40, 6, 8. Is this possible without creating another reference of person class which has this new object, something like this:public Person x = null;    public Person(int a, int b)
        {
            x = new Person(40, 6, 8);
        }
            
            Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", P.x.d, P.x.e, P.x.f);

Comment: @Saurabh: Then you must have done something wrong, because the code I've posted *does* compile. I've just verified it myself. Just changing your existing two-parameter constructor overload to either of the ones I've shown is fine. I never mentioned inheritance. Unfortunately it's hard to tell exactly what you've done wrong... you should get away from the notion of having another `Person` variable in your `Person` class... I'm pretty sure you *don't* want that. You should concentrate on working out what you've done compared with the code I've shown (which really does work).

Comment: @Saurabh: I think I've found out what you've done wrong. I suspect you've added the `: this(40, 6, 8)` to the constructor which takes *3* parameters, rather than the one which takes *two* parameters. Look carefully at the code I've provided.

Comment: Sorry Jon. You are correct. this code works for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

```
    public Person()
       : this(0,0,0)
    {
    }
    public Person(int a)
       : this(a,0,0)
    {
    }
    public Person(int a, int b)
       : this(a,b,0)
    {
    }
    public Person(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        d = a; e = b; f = c;
    }
```

Comment: No explanation whatsoever?

Comment: Just show what the error is. Author has to overload his contructors.

Comment: The author was already overloading the constructors. He wasn't chaining one overload to another though. I find code-only answers are *very* rarely as useful as ones which explain what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

The default value of an `int` is 0. Use `int?` and test if it has a value.

e.g.

```
var d = P.d.HasValue ? P.d : "";
var e = P.e.HasValue ? P.e : "";
var f = P.f.HasValue ? P.f : "";
Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", d, e, f);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write this

```
    public Person(int a, int b)
        : this(40, 6, 8)
    {
    }
```

to call the other constructor.

Comment: How in the world did my answer get accepted and not Jon Skeet's?! THE END IS NIGH! O_O

Comment: Well, I guess balanced was restored... <sad>